# How to fit child div inside parent div by any parallel sides, maintaining the ratio on resizeing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

so,the child div will contain an image and I need to be stretched to the side on vertical or on horizontal, depending on height or width(the images does not have the same height or width). Works great if I use zoom property or vw,vh(as you will see in jsfiddle), but the problem is that are not supported by most browsers(will be also an mobile website). I hope the jsfiddle will explan better what I need if not ask and will explain better.

```
.box {
position: absolute;
width: 70%;
height: 61.6%;
background-color: #ececec;
margin: auto;
top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;}
```

'content' div is the div that will wrap the image 
http://jsfiddle.net/s8Lmu6w5/

PS: you can use JS/JQuery. Becouse I think I tried 99% of html/css combinations....
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With an `<img>` element we can use `max-height: 100%` and `max-width: 100%`. The complete width of 100% is never reached, and the complete height of 100% is never reached, so the ratio remains 1:1

### Working Example

Note that the image is positioning itself in regards to the viewport and not it's parents in this example. You could remove all divs if wanted and have the same result.

**Compatibility**: Using this technique to centre the image vertically requires a max-height with a `px` length (not percentage) for the image to be centered in IE8.

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 61.6%;
  background-color: #ececec;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.content img {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='content'>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x500" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for the answer, I know how to to that. But the man I am working wants the image to behave like in the example I gave.

Comment: If you look at the updated example with a larger image, isn't that the same?

Comment: I tried a few different viewport and image sizes... they look the same to me. What am I not seeing?

Comment: off...I need more rep to post image. so in your example if you go full page, is a gap between top parent side and top child side(same as bottom since is centered). In any way I resize the page parallel sides(top-bottom or left-right)shoud be stretched to match the parent,but keeping the same ratio. Play with my jsfiddle and you will see that MAX 2 sides are not stretched, this is what I am looking for.